# Finding the probability density function

Tags: probability, density-function

> A random variable $Z$ is obtained as follows. Let $X$ follow $U(0, 1)$, and $Y$ given $X = x$ be Bernoulli with probability of success $x$. If $Y = 1, Z$ is defined to be $X$. Otherwise, the experiment is repeated until a pair $(X, Y )$ with $Y = 1$ is obtained. Then, find the probability density function of $Z$ on $(0, 1).$

Let $N$ be the trial number at which we get $Y=1$.
$F_Z(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(Z \leq z | N=n)P(N=n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(Z \leq z,y_n=1)P(y_1 \neq1)^{n-1}.$

Now, $P(Z \leq z,y_n=1)=P(Z \leq z |y_n=1)P(y_n=1)=P(X_n \leq z |y_n=1)P(y_n=1)=P(y_n=1 | X_n \leq z)P(X_n \leq z)$

I know $Y|X=x$ follows  $Ber(x)$, how can I proceed to find $P(y_n=1 | X_n \leq z)$ or $P(y_n=1, X_n \leq z)$?

Source: [Problem 29, ISI PSA 2021](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission/PreviousQuestion/MStat-PSA-2021.pdf)

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: @Zhanxiong It's from the MCQ part of the entrance exam conducted in 2021 for studying Masters in Statistics at the Indian Statistical Institute.

Comment: Thank you for the edits.  It is an interesting problem that combines many branches in probability together.

Comment: The distribution of $Z$ is the posterior for a Beta$(1,1)$ (Uniform) prior on a Bernoulli parameter when the Bernoulli observation is $1,$ whence it has a Beta$(1+1,1)$ distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting problem.  To formalize the definition of $Z$, it is helpful to introduce the positive integer-valued random variable $\tau$ (known as "*stopping time*" in probability theory):
\begin{align}
\tau = \min\{i: Y_i = 1\},
\end{align}
where $Y_i | X_i = x \sim B(1, x)$ and $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are i.i.d. $U(0, 1)$ random variables. With these notations, it is easy to see that $Z = X_\tau$. By the law of total probability, the CDF of $Z$ is given by ($0 < z < 1$):
\begin{align}
& F(z) = P[X_\tau \leq z] = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty P[X_i \leq z, \tau = i] \\
=& P[X_1 \leq z, Y_1 = 1] + \sum_{i = 2}^\infty P[X_i \leq z, Y_1 = \cdots = Y_{i - 1} = 0, Y_i = 1], \tag{1}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
P[X_1 \leq z, Y_1 = 1] = \int_{[X_1 \leq z]}P[Y_1 = 1|X_1]dP 
= \int_{[X_1 \leq z]}X_1dP = 
\int_0^zxdx = \frac{1}{2}z^2. \tag{2}
\end{align}
Here we used the definition of measure-theoretic conditional probability $P(A|\mathscr{G})$: for any $G \in \mathscr{G}$, $P(A \cap G) = \int_GP(A | \mathscr{G})dP$.

Similarly,
\begin{align}
P[Y_1 = 1] = \int_\Omega P[Y_1 = 1|X_1]dP = \int_\Omega X_1dP = \int_0^1 xdx = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}
It thus follows by independence that for $i \geq 2$
\begin{align}
 & P[X_i \leq z, Y_1 = \cdots = Y_{i - 1} = 0, Y_i = 1] \\
=& \prod_{k = 1}^{i - 1}P[Y_k = 0]P[X_i \leq z, Y_i = 1] 
= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{i - 1}\frac{1}{2}z^2 
= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^iz^2 . \tag{3}
\end{align}

Substituting $(2)$ and $(3)$ into $(1)$ yields
\begin{align}
F(z) = z^2\sum_{i = 1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^i = z^2.
\end{align}
Hence the density of $Z$ is $f(z) = 2z, 0 < z < 1$.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't really studied measure-theoretic probability, but I can intuitively understand what you did. What are you exactly using to find $P(Y_1=1)$? I can understand that we want to condition using $X$ and integrate over all possible values that $X$ can take, but, what is $G$ here?

Comment: @Tapi $G$ here is the full sample space $\Omega$, which is always in $\sigma(X)$. To put it in a more accessible way, you can proceed as $P(Y_1 = 1) = E[P(Y_1 = 1 | X)]$, i.e., using the law of iterative expectations.

Comment: So, you're using $P(Y_1=1 \cap \Omega)=P(Y_1=1)$. And yeah, it's easier to see it using the law of iterative expectations.

Comment: @Tapi Yes, using $P[Y_1 = 1] = P[[Y_1 = 1] \cap \Omega]$.  The reason I am using the posted presentation is to stay consistent with the treatment for $P[Y_1 = 1, X_1 \leq z]$, for which you can actually also use law of iterative expectations $P[Y_1 = 1, X_1 \leq z] = E[E[I_{[Y_1 = 1]}I_{[X_1 \leq z ]}| X_1]] = E[I_{[X_1 \leq z]}P[Y_1  = 1|X_1]] = \cdots$.

Comment: very interesting approach, thanks for explaining.